# How to assess whether a geographical point is within a region?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a list of agents each with geographical regions they may cover such as:
"Manhattan, New Jersey" for US 
or
"SW19, Putney, Bristol" for UK.

Given an address such as "101 7th Avenue, New York" or "119 merton road, wimbledon"; how could I query whether it address was within one regions above?

ie. Is "101 7th Avenue, New York" within "Manhattan"?

All regions above display as areas when searched in google maps.

Cheers!..
Miguel

Comment: If they display as "areas" when searched in google maps, the geocoder results may let you determine if they are in that polygon.  If that isn't possible, you could use polygons for the areas of interest and do point in polygon analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer geocodezip.  The google geocoder seems to return boxes (NE & SW coordinates) whereas the map itself displays a full polygon.  Is there any way to get this polygon from the geocoder?  Eg. 'SE1' in the [geocoder](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=se1&sensor=false) and in the [map](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=se1&hl=en&sll=51.451693,-0.011656&sspn=0.015966,0.045061&hnear=London+SE1,+United+Kingdom&t=m&z=13)